# Broken Button on Instagram Permissions Review? Instagram API - Start A Submission yields "Oops, there was an error"

Tags: api, permissions, instagram

Trying to start a new submission to request more permissions for our app w/ the Instagram API. Start A Submission button takes you to page that simply says "oops, there was an error." Happening w/ App Live, in Sandbox, and on both desktop and mobile. App as already been reviewed and approved; am seeking additional review for more permissions.

Anyone else experiencing or have a tip? I've submitted report to Instagram Developer Support.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Any updates?

Answer (score 2):

The Instagram API often just says "Oops an error occured !" and  donot give you any more information.

I think their servers timeout limit down.
Add the parameter distance=500, or even less, and you won't get this error any more.
Basically, in a high density area , you need to specify a small distance number, otherwise Instagram's server just times out while serving your request.